# Why is `execute` dropping back to the shell instead of sending SQL directly to my Postgres server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, shell, migration, execute

I have a migration which is using `execute` to send raw SQL to the Postgres backend.

```
class TestExecuteMethod < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    execute ('SELECT 1;')
  end

  def self.down
  end
end
```

Instead of going to my database, it seems `execute` is going to the shell:

```
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:migrate
==  TestExecuteMethod: migrating ==============================================

++ executing: SELECT 1;
sh: SELECT: command not found
++   [FAIL]
==  TestExecuteMethod: migrated (0.0041s) =====================================

** Invoke db:schema:dump (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:schema:dump
```

But, when I instead do

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

It works as expected.

Why is this?

I'm using Rails 3.0.9 and the `pg` gem.

Comment: What is the code  you are running that is returning the error?

Comment: Try type in `ALTER` on a shell -- what error do you get? (Yes, yes, I know, but this is to reinforce a point.) Now, what *really is* the `execute` method being used and where does it come from? (I believe it will be a "surprise" >:)

Comment: @Omar: The code could be a trivial `execute "select 1;"` but the result is the same, `sh: SELECT: command not found`.

Comment: sure - but, in what context are you running this exec? inside a migration, in a controller?

Comment: could you show us ALL the code inside that file? with a db:migrate --trace

Comment: @Omar: I've added the code you recommended

Comment: may not make a difference, but, remove the space between execute and (

Comment: Also, I agree with mu - this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your migration:

```
def self.trace_execute(io=$stderr, &block)
  set_trace_func proc {|event, file, line, id, binding, classname|
    io.printf "%8s %s:%-2d %10s %8s\n", event, file, line, id, classname if id.to_s == 'execute'
  }
  # trace the passed block
  yield

ensure
  # disable (note: the disable call is the last thing traced)
  set_trace_func nil
end
```

Then wrap your execute call in a block like this:

```
trace_execute { execute ('SELECT 1;') }
```

and paste the first few lines of trace output. I suspect something is intercepting the execute call before the db adapter can receive it.

Usually I'd recommend using something like

```
puts method(:execute).inspect
```

but that probably won't work in this case because method_missing is involved.

Comment: @jakeonrails For others' benefit, please explain how my answer solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

First glance is that execute is actually a shell exec - not a db exec.

I will be honest, I normally do use execute inside migrations - and that seems to work, i.e.

```
  def self.up
    execute <<EOF
some SQL
EOF
  end
```